# Number order of events

Tags: r

I am working on a project using medication history of patients, and I want to ask your help for this.
The database contains start dates of medication in random order, and I would like to number the medications in order of use.

So I would like to transform:

```
ID 001 002 003
medA 2001    2005    2003
medB 1999    2000    2015
medC 2019    2014    2000
```

To:

```
ID 001 002 003
medA 1 3 2
medB 1 2 3
medC 3 2 1
```

The real database has 700 subjects and 10+ medications.

Is there a way to do this in R?

Thanks in avance for your help!

NB this is my first post, please let me know if I'm doing something wrong forum-wise :)

Comment: Please share some reproducible data using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the original columns:

```
df[, paste0("rank", 1:3)] <- t(apply(df[,2:4], 1, rank))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach in base R:

```
#Your data
mydf <- structure(list(
ID = c("medA", "medB", "medC"), 
`001` = c(2001L,1999L, 2019L), 
`002` = c(2005L, 2000L, 2014L), 
`003` = c(2003L,                                                                                                                        2015L, 2000L)), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))

# Transform
mydf[,2:4] <- t(apply(mydf[,2:4], 1, order))

# Result
mydf
    ID 001 002 003
1 medA   1   3   2
2 medB   1   2   3
3 medC   3   2   1
```

In case more explanation is helpful:

- `order` is a function that returns the order of a numeric vector, such as a numeric row or a numeric column. For example: `order(c(6,4,5))` returns `2 3 1`.
- `mydf[, 2:4]` means the second column up to the fourth column of `mydf`.
- `apply` is a function that apply another function to each row or each column of a data frame or a matrix. In your case, `order` is to be applied to each row of `mydf[, 2:4]` so the index `1` is used. If a function is to be applied to each column, the index `2` should be used.
- `t` is a function to transpose a matrix or a data frame. In this case, it is used to restore the values in each row because when `order` is applied, the results are returned as columns, so they are transposed to be rows again.